# SRAM vs MicroSD

Tags: arm, cortex-m0

I have very little SRAM in my datalogger (10 kb), so I have to flush my buffer to MicroSD every 0.5 seconds. Would it make any difference in power usage if I added more SRAM (which is very difficult unfortunelately), and flush to SD every 30 seconds?

Or do SRAM and MicroSD both use about the same power, and will it be nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be wasting your time by adding anything additional.  It sounds to me like what you're doing at the moment is working perfectly well.

Your SD card only consumes appreciable power when you're writing to it, and the average power, i.e. the amount of energy consumed, is proportional to the amount of data you write, not how fast or how often you write it.  Adding a RAM buffer will increase your average power consumption (because you'll be powering the RAM), and it won't reduce the power consumption of your SD card.  The larger RAM buffer would also leave you at risk of losing more data in case of a power outage or battery failure.

An addendum: I wouldn't use more than 1kB of buffer space to do what you're doing - enough for two sectors on the SD card, or two 512B buffers.  When the first buffer fills, write it to the card.  While the write takes place, the second buffer starts to fill.  When the second buffer fills, write it to the card while you start filling the first buffer again.  This technique is sometimes called ping-pong buffering.  It's space-efficient in terms of RAM and it ensures that you will never lose more than 1kB of data if your system fails.

Comment: I already use exactly the same ping-pong buffering as you describe now, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your device could benefit from one of those serial SRAM chips. They come mostly in 8-pin DIP and SO packages. Think Microchip [23A1024](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25142A.pdf).

Of course, it won't be as quick as you on-chip memory, but if you only generate 10 kB of data in half a second, then speed shouldnt be a problem.

---

You get 128 kB of intermediate storage for $2 or so and very little board space. Also, they claim \$20\mu A\$ idle current.